# How to combine client side and server side validation?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-5

I have done some research, and I have seen that both client side and server side validation are possible together, (as mentioned in this post). However, I'm not just learning JavaScript, and I want to use Bootstrap for the client side validation, and use bootstraps `.is-invalid` and `.is-valid` classes for the server side validation. I heard that PHP was the best language to use for server side validation (Please correct me if I'm wrong on that), so I was going to use php. However my question is, is it possible to get the server to recognize that client-side validation is active so it only sends a request to the server if it is not active? I really only want server side validation as a fallback, in case a user disabled js in their browser or bypassed it some other way.

Comment: You can use php (or whatever ss language) to add those class names to your elements after you've validated your data to indicate their status, but the classes themselves don't do any validation.

Comment: Any server side language can do validation. You need to make a wider decision than that about which language to use to build whole server side infrastructure of your Web application. But none of that has anything to do with bootstrap or its css classes. Remember  that a big reason for doing server side validation is that the client side code can be bypassed easily - either the functionality could be disabled in the browser, or the program sending a http request to your server containing data might not be a browser at all. Your server has to validate all incoming data, no matter what

Comment: @mykaf I am aware of this, though I would like to have the server validate the form, though ONLY if client side validation is either disabled, or bypassed in some way.

Comment: *the server validate the form, ONLY if client side validation is either disabled or bypassed* - this defeats the whole point of having both UI and server-side validation.  The *client-side* validation is the "fallback" (if you want to use that term) - it's more a case of:  you always have server-side validation then have client-side validation as some nice UX icing on the top.

Comment: The server can never know that - it cannot even tell reliably if the http request it's received came from a browser, or from another program, let alone know what was happening in the browser (if any) at the time.

Comment: @ADyson I was going to use PHP for everything on the server side. However, I want to make it so the user can't recognize if the server is doing validation, if the client side validation is no longer functional.

Comment: Oh. Well how would I make the server side validation transparent to the user, so the user never recognizes it's the server?

Comment: If the client side validation isn't functional, then AJAX is likely off the table, so you'll have to at least submit your form to the server. But again, you can use the result of your server-side validation to set classes on your inputs, as well as any messages you would want to display.

Comment: @freedomn-m I guess the thing I'm trying to do is combine them. I want the user to only really see the client side validation, as it looks nicer, but have the server also validate the form so the user cannot bypass validation.

Comment: What do you mean "client side validation looks nicer"? You can make the result of your server-side validation look just like client-side.

Comment: A smart user would notice that a trip to the server had been made, because the page would refresh (unless you use ajax, but that wouldn't work at all if the user decides to disable JS - although arguably that's their problem, not yours). But as mykaf says you can present the results of the validation in exactly the same way, by mimicking what bootstrap would do for the same error. And why do you care if the user notices that or not, anyway??

Comment: Ultimately your philosophy must always be that the server side validation is the most important validation and has to be the most comprehensive and robust, because that's the one that cannot be easily bypassed. Client side validation is of secondary importance - it's just there to enhance the user experience, rather than be the primary enforcer of any rules. If you only consider the server side as a "fallback" option then you're asking for trouble. But of course if client side validation _is_ working, then it wouldn't ever invoke the server side validation.

Comment: Going back to "*my question is, is it possible to get the [browser] so it only sends a request to the server if [client-side validation] is not active? I really only want server side validation as a fallback, in case a user disabled js in their browser or bypassed it some other way."* - that is exactly how it works - if the form is not valid, then the client-side won't send the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it’s not recommended.
Keep the frontend validation just for user’s experience “and guidance”, you as a developer you should nerver nerver trust user’s input or frontend validation.

Avoid coupling the functionality of the two systems and isolate the decision-making processes of each entity.

1. Users can easily bypass client-side validation: Disabling JavaScript, using developer tools, or modifying requests can entirely circumvent client-side checks. Malicious users can exploit these weaknesses to submit invalid data even with client-side validation in place.
2. Server-side validation is essential for security: Never trust user input, regardless of any client-side checks. Server-side validation ensures critical data integrity and protects against potential security vulnerabilities like SQL injection or cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.
3. Combining them won't guarantee good results: While combining client-side and server-side validation can enhance user experience by providing instant feedback, it shouldn't replace thorough server-side validation. Client-side checks might fail due to various reasons, leaving your application vulnerable.

Comment: Ahh ok. I saw a way to have server side validation, but have it display results in a styled div which is what I want. Instead of sending the user to a ugly generated page saying the error alone.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to get the server to recognize that client-side validation is active so it only sends a request to the server if it is not active

No, you can't - the server doesn't even know if the HTTP request it receives came from a browser or some other type of client. It can't ever know what was going on in the browser (if any) at the time the request was made.

**But** that doesn't matter very much, because the server doesn't really *need* to recognise that. If the client-side validation is in place and working correctly, then it would prevent a request being sent to the server if the validation failed.

However if the client-side validation passes then the data will be sent to the server, and the server will still need to re-validate it, because it has no proof that any client-side validation has occurred, and no way of verifying the result of it either.

You can of course choose to present the results of any server-side validation errors in any way you wish - including mimicking the way the same error would be presented by the client-side validation, had it been active. Therefore you needn't be concerned that it would confuse users, or provide a significantly worse experience (aside from possibly an extra request to the server).

Finally: your server-side validation must be, in your mind, the most important validation and has to be the most comprehensive and robust, because that's the one that cannot be easily bypassed or disabled. Client-side validation is of secondary importance - it's just there to enhance the user experience, rather than be the primary enforcer of any rules. If you only consider the server side as a "fallback" option (the way you described it) then you're asking for trouble.

Comment: ok. Thank you for your amazing answer! I was mainly asking this because a previous project 9 tried creating a while back with php validatio looked very ugly. when the request was sent to the server, and was accepted, it would look very ugly. it would take the user to an empty page with the simple words "Logged In Successfully" or would still take the response, and take the user to a separate generated page with the JSON of what was wrong or not correctly entered, so the user would have to click the back button on the web browser.

Comment: I said use the server-side as a fallback, only because i thought it was impossible to keep the user on the same page when it was validated, and just use the bootstrap styles for the errors.

Comment: Ah OK, it sounds like the project you had previously just didn't have many features for presenting the validation results! But you have full control over how it's presented, if you want to. And yes I think I understand why you said fallback but I didn't want anyone else reading this to misunderstand :-) @Lil_PhyziX

Comment: Yes. I don't have much experience with PHP, in fact i know very little. So I don't really know how to get PHP to apply classes to HTML elements that show the error, instead of just generating a separate page to show the error. I heard it has something to do with the action attribute in the html input element.

Comment: @Lil_PhyziX Well PHP can generate HTML (or any other content), so one option is to get it to render HTML which has those classes in it. Or if the PHP returns a JSON object containing the validation errors, then maybe the client-side JS code (which might have submitted the form via AJAX, for example) can take those results and use them to show the relevant validation errors. It's up to you, depending how you've designed the rest of the application.

Comment: P.S. The html `input` element [doesn't have an action attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes) so I'm not entirely sure what you're referring to there. Did you mean a `form` element?